# Panda not reading rowspan

Tags: python, excel, pandas, html-table

I'm trying to convert Excel to HTML table using to_html.

[image: Table Structure]

I used the syntax:

```
file=pd.read_excel('Report11.xlsx',header=[0,1,2],columns=[2],inplace=True)
table_heading=file.to_html(classes=('tg',),justify='center')
print(table_heading)
```

It is displaying table in this format:

[image: Displayed Structure]

I want to remove the Unnamed level and display as rowspan.

Comment: A pandas DataFrame must be rectangular. It does not support "spans."

Comment: Then? What should I do. You have any idea?

Comment: What you do depends on your goal. Why do you want a dataframes with that row removed?

Comment: I want to display the same format in Html page. With row and cell merger.

Comment: The purpose of a dataframe is not to display but to compute.